# Laplace transform to determine system output

Tags: laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

I have the following question:
*Below, differential equations that describe dynamic systems are given together with system inputs and initial conditions. Use the Laplace transform to determine the system outputs.*

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2} y}{\mathrm{~d} t^{2}}+3 \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{~d} t}+2 y &=\sigma(t) \\
\sigma(t) &=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0, & t<0 \\
1, & t \geq 0
\end{array}\right.\\
\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{~d} t}(0)=y(0) &=0
\end{aligned}
$$

After using the  $\mathcal{L}$-transform and partial fraction decomposition, I come to :

$$
Y(s) = \frac{1}{s+1} - \frac{1}{s+2}$$
which I tranform back to $\mathcal{L}^{-1} = e^{-t} - e^{-2t}$.
The correct answer is : $\frac{1}{2} -e^{-t} + \frac{1}{2} e^{-2t}$.

I am self-taught so I probably missed something very basic here, but after looking up many examples, I don't understand why this is the right answer.
Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laplace transform of $1$ is $\frac1s$. Probably you'd have taken it as $1$ and so obtained the wrong result.

It is actually, $$Y(s) = \frac{1}{\color{blue}{s}(s^2+3s+2)} = \frac{1}{s(s+1)(s+2)} = \frac1{2s} - \frac1{s+1} + \frac1{2(s+2)}$$

So, $$\boxed{y(t) = \frac12 - e^{-t} + \frac12e^{-2t}}$$

Comment: Wait I thought Laplace(()) = 1?
At which moment shall I do the replacement?

Comment: Nope, Laplace $\sigma(t \ge 0) =$ Laplace $(1) = \frac1s$ . So you'd be having $s^2Y(s) + 3sY(s) + 2 Y(s) = \frac1s$